# Regex to capture all numbers in a string that ends with a number

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to write a regex that captures all the numbers in a string BUT only if the string ends with numbers.

I worked out the pattern would require a repeating capture group:

```
^(\D*(\d+))+$
```

So

- the string starts
- there are 0 or more non-digit characters
- then 1 or more digits (which we capture)
- that pattern repeats until the end of the string

My problem is that it seems that in repeated capture groups you only get the last match returned to you. ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZDQWIg/1))

Can anyone show me where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Not clear. So, string `a1a2a3a4` would matche `1, 2, 3, 4`, and `a1a2a3a` would match nothing?

Comment: @PeterThoeny That is correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this regex with a lookahead:

```bash
\d+(?=(?:\w+\d)?\b)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZDQWIg/3)

**RegEx Breakdown:**

- `\d+`: Match 1+ digits
- `(?=`: Start Lookahead assertion

  - `(?:\w+\d)?`: Optionally match 1 or more word characters followed by a digit
  - `\b`: Word boundary
- `)`: End Lookahead assertion

Comment: Hello sir, for condition `BUT only if the string ends with numbers.` just for my knowledge how are we fulfilling it? Thank you sir 

Comment: We have a lookahead assertion here `(?=(?:\w+\d)?\b)` that is making sure that we have a digit just before word boundary after matching 1 or more word characters.